# React Native - babel.config.js alias not seeing files outside the current working directory

Tags: react-native, babeljs, babel-loader, metro-bundler, babel-plugin-module-resolver

So, my project is monorepo. There are folders for web application, mobile application, etc. And there is also a `common` folder, where gathered all the reusable components and utils.

```
<repo-name>
├── app // mobile app
│   ├── node_modules
│   ├── src
│   │   ├── views
│   │   │   ├── Homepage
│   │   │   │   └── index.tsx
│   │   └── App.tsx
│   ├── babel.config.js
│   ├── tsconfig.json
│   └── ...
├── common
│   ├── utils
│   │   └── format.ts
├── web
│   ├── app
│   │   ├── tsconfig.json
│   │   └── ...
│   ├── landing
│   │   ├── tsconfig.json
│   │   └── ...
```

`App.tsx` has schematically the next content:

```js
import React from "react"
import Homepage from "views/Homepage"
import { someFunction } from "@common/utils/format"

export default
class App
extends React.Component<any, any> {
    render() {
        return <>
            <h1>{someFunction("kappa")}</h1>
            <Homepage />
        <>
    }
}
```

Mobile app's `tsconfig.json` looks like this:

```json
{
    "extends": "@tsconfig/react-native/tsconfig.json",
    "compilerOptions": {
        "baseUrl": ".",
        "experimentalDecorators": true,
        "useDefineForClassFields": true,
        "strictNullChecks": true,
        "noUnusedLocals": true,
        "noUnusedParameters": true,
        "paths": {
            "@common/*": [
                "../common/*",
            ],
            "*": [
                "./src/*",
                "node_modules",
            ],
        }
    },
}
```

and the `babel.config.js` is this:

```js
module.exports = {
    presets: ['module:metro-react-native-babel-preset'],
    plugins: [
        [
            "@babel/plugin-transform-flow-strip-types",
            { legacy: true },
        ],
        [
            "@babel/plugin-proposal-decorators",
            { legacy: true },
        ],
        [
            "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties",
            { "loose": false }
        ],
        [
            'module-resolver',
            {
                root: ['./src'],
                extensions: ['.ios.js', '.android.js', '.js', '.ts', '.tsx', '.json'],
                alias: {
                    "@common": "../common",
                }
            }
        ]
    ]
};
```

Basically, what's going on.
I've created alias for `common` folder content to be imported as `@common/...`
Also, all content from `src` folder can be imported without relative paths.

This aliases are configured in both `tsconfig.json` and `babel.config.json`. I'm using VSCode, and autocomplete for `@common` alias works flawlessly.

But in runtime (inside Metro CLI) I'm getting this error:

```
Error: Unable to resolve module ../../common/utils/format from /home/<username>/projects/<project>/<repo-name>/app/src/App.tsx: 

None of these files exist:
  * ../common/utils/format(.native|.android.js|.native.js|.js|.android.jsx|.native.jsx|.jsx|.android.json|.native.json|.json|.android.ts|.native.ts|.ts|.android.tsx|.native.tsx|.tsx)
  * ../common/utils/format/index(.native|.android.js|.native.js|.js|.android.jsx|.native.jsx|.jsx|.android.json|.native.json|.json|.android.ts|.native.ts|.ts|.android.tsx|.native.tsx|.tsx)
```

As you can see, path for `@common` is resolved perfectly, but for some reason babel does not see `format.ts` file.

What I'm doing wrong? Is there any caveats, any workarounds?
Any help appreciated. Spent abount 4 hours on this problem and found nothing useful.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, so, basically, this is not a problem of the Babel.
Turns out that Metro does not know a thing about folders outside the project.

Well, all you need is to add `watchFolders` property to `metro.config.js`:

```js
/**
 * Metro configuration for React Native
 * https://github.com/facebook/react-native
 *
 * @format
 */

const path = require("path")

module.exports = {
  transformer: {
    getTransformOptions: async () => ({
      transform: {
        experimentalImportSupport: false,
        inlineRequires: true,
      },
    }),
  },
  // here we should set folders outside of the project folder
  // to be able to import modules from 'em
  watchFolders: [
    path.resolve(__dirname + "/../common")
  ]
};
```

Two days searching and the solution is, as always, just 4 rows

The beautiful world of javascript bundlers.
That's all folks!
¯\_(ツ)_/¯